# How two independent jmp_bufs work?

Tags: c, setjmp

Hi I want to ask about setjmp/longjmp. I tried to search, but I was unsucessuful...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf a, b;

void jump() {
    int aa = setjmp(a);

    if (aa)
    {
        printf("Jump!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        longjmp(b, 1); 
        printf("Should not happened...\n");
    }

    printf("End of function!\n");
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int bb = setjmp(b);

    if (bb)
    {
        longjmp(a, 1);
        printf("Should not happened...\n");
    }
    else
    {
        jump();
        printf("What here?\n");
    }

    printf("Exit\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The question is, what will happen after last printf in jump()... I tried this code and it turned into infinite loop. Why? I though that setjmp will store environment data, so the jump function shall return after it's original call... I'm quiet confused. Thanks for reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole program has undefined behavior.

1. `setjmp(b);` stores the stack state.
2. `jump()` is called.
3. `setjmp(a);' stores the stack state again.
4. `longjmp(b, 1);` restores the stack to the point before `jump()` was ever called.  So the state stored in `a` is now invalid.
5. Execution continues at the `if` in `main()`.
6. `longjmp(a, 1);` is called. Ouch.  This causes undefined behavior due to 4 above.

Your confusion probably results from the slightly imprecise use of the world "return" in the Linux docs for `setjmp()`.

> The stack context will be invalidated if the function which called `setjmp()` returns.

In your example, the function `jump()` didn't return in the normal way, but the effect was the same: the stack was "chopped" by the first `longjmp()` to the state before `jump()`, which is what a return does, too.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know some useful page or literaure where I can find more information about C and stack? Maybe my imagination of it is slightly different than reality is :)